# DoubleClick svg element

Tags: svg

I have an svg element, on performing double click action on it, it should open a widget box. While doing double click it is not throwing any error, but it is not opening the widget box. Here is my code :

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[name()='svg'] /*[name()='g']"));

Actions builder2 = new Actions(driver);
Action a2 = builder2.doubleClick(element).build();
a2.perform();

WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver,120);
WebElement config = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.xpath(".//*[@id='xwt_widget_layout_Dialog_3']")));
```

Not able to get the widget box. Please help me with this one.

Comment: I think this is going to be difficult. The SVG standard doesn't define a double click event, and [Firefox provide no support for double clicks in SVGs](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=360145). The same may apply to other browsers too. You could probably kludge something together with `onclick` handlers and timeout events. Or you could use HTML instead.